# How can I implement a convolutional LSTM cell in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is the correct general approach to simply copy all of the code of `class BasicLSTMCell(RNNCell)` and replace all the matrix multiplication with conv2d operations? What are things that I have to keep in mind when implementing it this way?

Comment: Did you mean "convolutional LSTM"? If so, yes, that's the basic idea. You can build your own subclass of RNNCell using convolutions. (There may already be one out there you can use; perhaps someone else will know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the basic idea. I got an implementation of it working in tensorflow [here](https://github.com/loliverhennigh/Convolutional-LSTM-in-Tensorflow). It can generate videos that look like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjZ1VKYyHhs). They seem to work surprisingly well. I edited the `rnn_cell.py` file to get it working.